# Meaning of the output from lsblk command

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, lsblk

I have recently started using Linux and would love to know how to interpret the output from the `lsblk -f` command.

More specifically, I would like to know the different partitions and sizes.

- For instance, I understand that ext4 and xfs are different file systems in unix. But the entire picture has a tree structure. So I was wondering if the total number of partitions is 4, i.e.,sda1, sda2, sda3 and sdb.
- If so, then what are the sub-partitions (root, swap, home and var)?
- Also, is lvm2_member a filesystem too?

```
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL MOUNTPOINT   SIZE
sda                                            1.1T
├─sda1                                           2M
├─sda2          xfs               /boot          2G
└─sda3          LVM2_member                    1.1T
  ├─centos-root ext4              /            200G
  ├─centos-swap swap              [SWAP]       128G
  ├─centos-var  ext4              /var          10G
  └─centos-home ext4              /home        777G
sdb             ext4        data  /data       81.9T
loop1           squashfs                     487.5M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two disks, `sda` and `sdb`. Your second disk, `sdb` doesn't have a partition table and is formatted directly to `ext4`. Your first disk has 3 partitions, `sda1` (from its size, I assume it's a [BIOS boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition)), `sda2` used for `/boot` and `sda3` which is used as [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) Physical Volume (or `LVM2_member` as shown by `lsblk` here).

[LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) (Logical Volume Manager) provides another "abstraction" layer for storage -- it allows you to "merge" multiple block devices (partitions or disks) to a Volume Group (or VG, your VG is named `centos`) and create new block devices, called Logical Volumes (or LVs) inside the VG. You have 4 LVs for your `/`, `/home`, `/var` and `swap`. You can picture LVs as just another layer of partitions on top of `sda3` (it's more complicated than that, but you don't really need to worry about that).

LVM is not really needed or that much helpful with a single disk, but it is the default storage layout in CentOS and it offers a lot of useful features. For example if you add third disk in the future you can add it to your existing `centos` VG and grow your `/home` (for example) using space on the second disk, it offers support for creating snapshots, caching, RAID, clustering etc. It's also way easier to resize LVs than partitions (e.g. shrinking `/home` and using the newly created free space for `/` would be way harder with partitions). If you are interested in details I recommend [Logical Volume Manager Administration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/index) guide from Red Hat.